# iPhone - animating a view controller presentation

Tags: iphone

I have a UINavigationControl and I would like to present a view controller pushing it from the top and removing it from the view pushing it to the top.

Is there a way to change the default animation used when you call

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:myViewController animated:YES];
```

to another animation instead of pushing right to left or do I have to animate it myself?

In the second case, how do I do that?

thanks.

Comment: This is a bit non-standard. Animating from the top will conceal the navigation bar of the current top view controller.

Comment: I don't have a visible navigation bar on this controller. But anyway lets say that I would like to animate it pushing to the right instead of the default to the left... how do I do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Import Quartzcore framework
add header line in .h file

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
```

than where you need to call next viewController, just add this animation line

```
CATransition *animation = [CATransition animation];
[animation setDelegate:self];
[animation setType:kCATransitionPush];
[animation setSubtype:kCATransitionFromRight];
[animation setDuration:0.2f];
[animation setTimingFunction:[CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut]];
[[self.view layer] addAnimation:animation forKey:@"pushIn"];
```

Here is call to view controller and add in super view, when you BACK TO this view, just add same animation maintain only left and right, than set removeFromSuperView..

```
classObj = [[ClassController alloc] initWithNibName:@"Xib Name" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
[self.view addSubview:classObj.view];
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is an excellent tutorial on creating your own animations for your UIViews.

http://developer.apple.com/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_intro/chapter_1_section_1.html

Comment: thanks but I am tring to animate a viewController presentation, not a view.

Comment: There is no difference between a viewcontroller and a UIView. All UIControls including the viewcontroller are inherited from UIView.

Comment: Yes Craig is right, you can also animate the viewcontroller even the navigation controller as well.You just need to use controllers view to animate instead of self.view.
+1 for Craig